# Python requests won't work on my kivy app

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

So I've been making a web scraper app for android using kivy. Of course, I have to use a web scraper. My choice is the requests library of python. My code goes like this:

```
def refresh_chapters(href):
    site = requests.get(url=href)
    tree = html.fromstring(site.content)

    links = tree.xpath('//a//@href')

    for i in range(17):
        links.pop(0)

    for i in range(3):
        links.pop(-1)

    labels = tree.xpath('//a//@title')

    file1 = open("resources/chapter_labels.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
    file2 = open("resources/chapter_links.txt", "w")

    size = len(links)

    for i in range(size):
        file1.writelines(labels[i] + "\n")
        file2.writelines(links[i] + "\n")
```

This code takes a url `href` parameter and scans the page for the desired labels and links. The function itself works fine on its own. The problem pops up when I integrate it to my main program. There's nothing particularly special about the main code. There's just a button that's set to pass on a parameter to the function. When I run it through the main.py file, then the request will come back empty. I know this because on the `links.pop(0)` part of the code, it throws the `IndexError: pop from empty list` error. This only happens when I integrate it to the main file. It runs as intended on a separate file. I already tried importing it, defining it on the main file, and even defining it within the class containing the button. I've racked my brain for this and I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I know this may sound retarded but check that the value passed into the function 'href' is accurate. I'm inferring that it's a string of a particular format. Check for whitespace before and after the string. Check for substituted characters. Also, a unittest might help you understand any changes that might have occured.

Comment: Does your problem only occur on Android? does your code run correctly on a PC?

Comment: @DarnellBaird yep. my href is correct. I inserted a print statement so I can monitor what was being passed while testing.

Comment: @JohnAnderson The problem is there in the pc. It's the function. It just won't work when I integrate it to the main file.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve].